# Connect to SQL Server 2012 from an Windows XP client

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

We have an SQL Server 2012 Standard database, to connect to it we use SQL Server 2008 Management Studio (since 2012 SSMS is not supported on Windows XP).
The problem is that SQL Server 2008 gives all the time an exception (Index outside the bounds of the array) and it's not possible to edit table in visual editor or open table. Client can work now only with database objects through queries.
So the question is - is there any solution on Windows XP to work properly with 2012 database ?

Comment: the native client here:
http://www.microsoft.com/de-de/download/confirmation.aspx?id=16978 should help, hk

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try upgrading SSMS to the SQL Server 2008 R2 version.  A client that I had I was using SSMS 2008 R2 to connect to SQL 2012 without issue.  It doesn't support the new features but it'll work.

The best option would be to upgrade to a new OS which is under support (I say as I boot up my Windows XP VM to do some stuff).

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I installed SSMS R2 SP2 and it works much better, the only thing that's not working is tables editor - it doesn't open, the rest of the bugs was fixed

Comment: Good to know about SP2. The tables editor has some quirks anyway, so it is usually better to script changes.

Answer (score 9):

The version of Management Studio you should be using is SQL Server 2012. Sadly - as you've confirmed - [this is not supported on Windows XP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17834976/install-sql-server-2012-management-tools-on-windows-xp). I don't think this is a wholly artificial restriction - I think even if you could figure out some way to hack the 2012 tools into installing, you'd have other behavioral issues to deal with.

So, you have a couple of options (and I understand that these may or may not be practical):

1. Upgrade to a new version of Windows (and if you need XP for compatibility reasons, use [XP mode](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/products/features/windows-xp-mode)). You won't get a whole lot of sympathy from Microsoft running a 10-year old operating system.
2. Remote to the SQL Server 2012 machine and use *its* copy of Management Studio.
3. Deal with / ignore the exception (though you may be missing other functionality too).

Answer (score 1):

I had an issue where an old server needed to read data from a new server for backwards compatibility.  The old server cannot be upgraded as it contains a legacy system that is being deprecated, but still used.  I needed SQL Server 2012, downloaded it and it refused to run on Server 2003 SP2.  I used Orca and removed the installrequirement, and it installed and runs just fine...there was some weirdness in the installer but PHP is using the library successfully.